# 1 Mbit = ? bytes

Tags: standards, bit, megabyte

I always get confused about this.  Is there a "standard" conversion of Megabits to bytes?

Is it:

```
 1 Megabit == 1,000,000 bits == 125,000 bytes
```

Or:

```
 1 Megabit == 2^20 bits == 1,048,576 bits == 131,072 bytes
```

Comment: The wonderful thing about standards is that there are so many to choose from.

Comment: @Rob pretty much nails it. Both are widely-used. Strictly speaking, `Mega` etc. are SI prefixes and stand for powers of ten, but many many millions of people don't give a damn about that.

Comment: Side note: often when talking of Kbits/Mbits the number is "gross", not taking in account protocol overhead. The conversion to useful bytes may be different from a simple division by 8.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Megabits is a unit of measure that comes from TELECOM, not CS. So it is:

```
 1 Megabit == 1,000,000 bits == 125,000 bytes
```

When it's a CS based unit of measure, usually the `1024` rules apply:

```
 1 Megabyte = 1,024 Kilobytes = 1,024 x 1,024 bytes
```

Comment: Also, the unit **Mebibyte** (MiB) is now used for binary-based values  (*1024 rules*) versus the now SI approved base-10 **Megabyte**. All but Microsoft uses the new unit meanings in their operating systems.

Comment: @Pablo Santa Cruz Now I'm confused. [Google disagrees with you.](http://www.google.com/search?q=megabit%20to%20byte) - it says "1 megabit = 131 072 byte". I know nothing about this, so I might just have misunderstood.

Comment: @Blowski: Don't know where you get that Google says that 1 muegabit = 131072 bytes. But check out wiki: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Megabit

Comment: @Blowski: The number 125,000 comes from 1,000,000/8. 1 bytes = 8 bits.

Comment: @Pablo Santa Cruz I put the link above - it's just searching on Google for `megabit to byte` and Google Calculator returns "1 megabit = 131 072 byte". I'm not saying you're wrong - just trying to clear up a discrepancy between Google and Wikipedia. I suspect they're both right, referring to different things, but to the lay man it looks like they disagree.

Comment: google tells me 1 MBit = 131072 bytes see: https://www.google.com/search?q=1+megabit+to+byte

Comment: When I click your search link I get 1 MBit = 125000 bytes from Google.

Answer (score 3):

One *megaoctet* (only the same as a megabyte [if each byte has eight bits](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte)) is eight megabits. Exactly the same conversion applies as for megabytes.

- A one "megabit" RAM, ROM, or flash memory chip has 1024<sup>2</sup> mebibits (Mibit) = 1 048 576 bits.
- A one megabit per second Internet connection can transfer 1000<sup>2</sup> megabits (Mbit) = 1 000 000 bits per second.

So four different conversions of "megabits" to "megabytes" may apply (assuming that each byte does have eight bits):

- 1 Mibit (mebibit) = 8 MiB (mebibytes) = 8 388 608 B = 8.388608 MB (megabytes)
- 1 Mbit (megabit) = 8 MB (megabytes) = 8 000 000 B ≈ 7.6294 MiB (mebibytes)

Answer (score 1):

It's the former.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Megabit

Comment: Google says 1 Megatbit = 1.049e+6 bits

Answer (score 1):

1 megabit = 0.125 megabyte

[google it](http://www.google.com/search?q=megabit%20to%20byte&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a#hl=en&sugexp=ldymls&pq=megabit%20to%20byte&xhr=t&q=megabit%20to%20megabyte&cp=13&qe=bWVnYWJpdCB0byBtZWJ5dGU&qesig=u-Gl4zOY4c1mlEQVc0jwOg&pkc=AFgZ2tnSf6UndWN3J1ne7_-_vpQ0IP4KX2FurE2WHnZLclvKv5H8nmajMK_OWnLMwvyThHMMh5VbjXhHueFYy-5iqbEUb8Tsyg&pf=p&sclient=psy&client=firefox-a&hs=Jat&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&biw=1181&bih=705&source=hp&aq=0l&aqi=&aql=&oq=megabit%20to%20mebyte&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=c9365e657b732f11)

Alright, I didn't mean for my answer to cause such uproar, but as all of your comments are valid, I figured I would come back to help clear up my reputation a bit.

I believe the correct answer to the whole question is that a

- Megabit is 1,000,000 Bits
- Mebibit is 1,048,576 Bits
- Megabyte is 8,000,000 Bits
- Mebibyte is 8,388,608 Bits

So the original question is not a matter of which one is correct, but that they have the wrong name to the label.

```
1 Megabit == 2^20 bits == 1,048,576 bits == 131,072 bytes
```

Should instead be:

```
1 Mebibit == 2^20 bits == 1,048,576 bits == 131,072 bytes
```

Comment: This wonderfully puts off the question 1000 vs 1024 by ignoring it!

Comment: This answer states: `1 Megabit == 131,072 bytes`

Comment: -1 he clearly searched before and is asking a very specific and valid question. No need for the google link here.

Comment: 1 Didn't answer what was a pretty reasonable question.

Comment: ..and I have changed my mind about your answer as it seems to muddy the waters on the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

**Kilo** is 1.000, **Mega** is 1.000.000 times of whatever it is. Such as **Kilo**gram is 1.000 gram. **Kilo**hertz is 1.000 hertz so on.

Same for Mega, **Mega**Hertz is 1.000.000 hertz, **Mega**bit is 1.000.000 bit.

Since 1 byte is 8 bit, then 1.000.000 / 8 = 125.000 byte.

When it comes to computer, the multiplier changes slightly, such as Kilo is 1024 times and Mega is 1024*1024 = 1.048.576 times of whatever it is (in generally bit).

In this case 1 MegaBit  = 1.024 * 1.024 = 1.048.576 bits, in terms of byte 1.048.576/8 = 131.072 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

While there is a movement to introduce `Mebi` and the like as the measurement for the power of two units, the usage isn't universial or accepted. However, from experience, bits are most likely to be depicted with the normal definition of `Mega`, so `1,000,000 bits`.

Answer (score 0):

It may vary by industry.  Component manufacturers offering FLASH products advertise their products as "1Mbit" and contain "131,072 bytes".  (Reference: SST's 1 Mbit SPI Bus Serial FLASH [(PDF Datasheet)](http://www.sst.com/dotAsset/40510.pdf); indexable addresses 0h-1FFFFh)

Answer (score 0):

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UnitsPolicy

UNIT POLICY. this is new unit policy for all 2 base and 10 base units

The binary meanings are more commonly used in relation to solid-state memory (such as RAM)

while the decimal meanings are more common for data transmission rates, disk     storage and in theoretical calculations in modern academic textbooks."

for more innformation see

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Manual_of_Style/Dates_and_numbers#Quantities_of_bytes_and_bits